# Unable to Load Markers into LeafLet

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, maps, leaflet

I read [this example from LeanPub](https://leanpub.com/leaflet-tips-and-tricks/read#leanpub-auto-make-sure-you-get-the-most-up-to-date-copy-of-leaflet-tips-and-tricks) where I learned to get coordinates for Bus Stops. I followed the steps & was able to successfully get the Coordinates from BusStops.php as follow

```
var BusStopsCordinates = [[-40.994970,174.508080],[-41.302690,173.636960],[-41.494130,173.542100],[-40.985850,174.506590],[-40.931630,173.817260],[-41.518300,174.780810],[-41.420790,173.578300],[-42.084140,173.966320],[-41.512850,173.532740]];
```

Following the steps. I called this BusStops.php file into javascript on my Index.html page as follows.

```
<script>
<?php include 'busstops.php'; ?>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-40.994970, 174.508080], 18);
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

    for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([planes[i][0],planes[i][1]])
            .addTo(map);
    }        
</script>
```

According to the exmple i should get result like this.
[image]

but i am getting no result at all. I am new to PHP & Leaflet. Please tell me where is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you just forgot to replace the `planes` variable from the example by your `BusStopsCordinates` variable?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/28/

Comment: No. I was replacing code back that is why i forgot to set BusStopsCordinates. I have used BusStopsCordinates but it is not working. Please can you edit this demo where u get the result from my PHP File here [link](websitedevelopers.com.pk/karachi/web/xml/busstops.php). Even though it is producing var BusStops the way u used in your demo, it is not working for me.

Comment: Seems to be still working? http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/29/ (I use an intermediate `L.featureGroup` just to retrieve the bounds of your new markers, which are at a totally different world position than the example).

Comment: I want to get result from my PHP file. Like in my code i used `<?php include 'busstops.php'; ?>`, It is supposed to get var  BusStopsCordinates from that PHP file but its not getting. Can u use `<?php include 'busstops.php'; ?>` in ur demo so i will understand it correctly. I tried it the whole day but not working for me. :/

Comment: Are you generating the HTML page on server side with PHP? Please note that PHP is executed on the server, not in the browser. If you want to import external data but cannot generate the full HTML page on server, you can import partial contents from browser by many other means. E.g. try jQuery getScript or ajax (the latter would need just JSON content). Updated demo with jQuery.getScript: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/30/